# react-table 7 custom cell says data undefined

Tags: react-table-v7

In version 6 this used to work, some of the rows doesn't have price, but `original` should be pointing to the row.

```
        {
            accessor : 'price',
            Header: () => <b>Price</b>,
            style: { 'whiteSpace': 'unset' },
            Cell: ({original}) => original.price && <div className="full-center">{original.price}</div>,
        },
```

But after upgraded to version 7, now I am getting `LineMatchingPage.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a subtle change in version 7, that accessor returns the value gets fed into `Cell`, so in this case, in version 7, `original` does not represent the row anymore, but the value of the `accessor` which is the value of the `price`

```
    {
        accessor : 'price',
        Header: () => <b>Price</b>,
        style: { 'whiteSpace': 'unset' },
        Cell: ({price}) => price && <div className="full-center">{price}</div>,
    },
```